# How to update a specific value in a specific line of a text file c#

Tags: c#

For example each line in my text file has the format of `element1,element2,element3`, I have an `id` int to be able to identify which line I want to edit this is done by comparing `id` with `element3`, and I want to be able to replace `element1` with the string `EditCategoryInput`. Then I want to write all the array elements from txtData back to my file.

This is my code so far that is not working:

```
 var itemFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Categories.txt");

 string[] txtData = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(itemFile);
 int count = 0;
 foreach(string row in txtData)
 {
   if (row.Split(',')[2] == Convert.ToString(id))
   {
     txtData[count] = txtData.Select(s => s.Replace(row.Split(',')[2], EditCategory)).ToArray();
   }
   count++;  
 }
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(itemFile, txtData);
```

The error is in this line:

```
txtData[count] = txtData.Select(s => s.Replace(row.Split(',')[2], EditCategory)).ToArray();
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track or if I am completely lost, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working. Is it not writing to the file, is it throwing an exception or is it not replacing the values correctly?

Comment: `count++` - Why is that inside an else block?

Comment: @Tronald its throwing an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild your line collection with new values. YOu need to take it apart and re-assemble

```cs
foreach(string line in lines)
{
    string[] items = line.Split(',');

    if (items[2] == id.ToString())
    {
        items[0] = EditCategoryInput;
    }
    newLineList.Add(string.Join(',', items )); // add your new or unchanged line to new line collection
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to rebuild it in the same position that it was in for example if its index was txtData[0] and then to rebuild it so that its index would still be txtData[0]...if that makes sense?

Comment: @Vassilis this is exactly what my example shows. When you do `line.Split(',')` your `items[0]` is `x`. Then you assign new value to it `items[0] = EditCategoryInput`, and re-build the line `string.Join`.